# Remove duplicate ids based on a particular criteria in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have the data in the following format : Date, Id, eventDate. Now Id can be duplicate.
We need to pick only those rows where 0<=eventdate -date <=6. There should be one row for one id only . Event date for each id is constant.

The date basically span four consecutive weeks of a year

Eg the data I am reading in pig is like

```
01-03-2014,  33578,  01-03-2014
08-03-2014,  57689,  10-03-2014
15-03-2014,  67890,  21-03-2014
15-03-2014,  57689,  10-03-2014
22-03-2014,  33578,  01-03-2014
22-03-2014,  67890,  21-03-2014
22-03-2014,  33578,  01-03-2104
22-03-2014   67890,  21-03-2014
```

Answer would be

```
01-03-2014,  33578,  01-03-2014
08-03-2014,  57689,  10-03-2014
15-03-2014,  67890,  21-03-2014
```

Only one row for each id based on the logic above.

Comment: Is it possible that 0<=eventdate -date <=6 gives more than one row?

Comment: No, it wont be as we are having only weeks data starting first day of the week. So, it will be only one row.

Answer (score 0):

If only one row can be found for each Id, why don't you use just simple filter with condition `0<=eventdate -date <=6`.

Edit:
I'm sure, someone can do it better with 'magic udf functions', but with BuildIn functions it could look like this:

```
a = load 'stack.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (date : chararray, id:chararray, eventdate:chararray);
b = foreach a
  {
  date_yyyy = SUBSTRING(date,8,10);
  date_mm = SUBSTRING(date,3,5);
  date_dd = SUBSTRING(date,0,2);
  eventdate_yyyy = SUBSTRING(TRIM(eventdate),8,10);
  eventdate_mm = SUBSTRING(TRIM(eventdate),3,5);
  eventdate_dd = SUBSTRING(TRIM(eventdate),0,2);
  int_date = (int)(CONCAT(CONCAT(date_yyyy,date_mm),date_dd));
  int_eventdate = (int)(CONCAT(CONCAT(eventdate_yyyy,eventdate_mm),eventdate_dd));
  generate date, id, eventdate, CONCAT(CONCAT(eventdate_yyyy,eventdate_mm), eventdate_dd), int_eventdate - int_date as diff;
  };
c = FILTER b by (diff >= 0 and diff <= 6);
```

Still unsolved problem with providing one row for each id that doesn't make `(diff >= 0 and diff <= 6)` condition. 
I'll do it as soon a s I get the answer: which row to take for duplicated ids?

Comment: Thanks @Pawel. Yeah the thing is your filtering criteria eventdate - date <=6 will work in case of duplicate ids (like if same id visits on 1st and 8th). But if there is no duplicate occurence of id then I will like to pick the only row which exists. Like 01-03-2014,  478,  21-03-2014. Now, this 478 id does not occur anywhere else, then I want this row to be included in the result set.

Comment: What if none of the records for id meets criteria eventdate - date <=6 and there is more that one left for each id? Which one to pick? And what is the number of records to process?

Comment: many thanks. I have the UDFS with me . Sorry should have told you earlier. I am more specifically looking at what would a good condition. We will have only 4 or 5 Sundays as possible dates. But an id can get duplicated on these dates or it could be unique. We basically need to pick that row which is nearest Sunday before the eventday. So, if the id appears once only on Date 01-03-2014 with event day as 22-03-2014 , then it will be considered. However, if the id had duplicated on later dates 8, 15 or 22 , then that particular date would have been picked up.

Comment: Tahnks @Pawel. Anyway we can handle this criteria

Comment: Is it solved then? Do you know how to get one record for ids that don't meet criteria?

Comment: No, for Ids that dont meet the criteria, I am still stuck. Because I want to dump that info as well.